# arrayList with 2+ objects stored, how to get a return if user searches for them

Tags: java, file, arraylist, return-value

so with the program, the user inputs data for the object in one file Inv.java and then that information is stored in Product.java and in store.java. from store.java there is an arrayList which holds the information but when 2 items are attempted to be put in, the second object writes over the first, how can I fix this and how can I be able to call the objects back in Inv.java

code for Inv.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Inv
{


public static void main(String args[])
{

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str;
    char c;
    int n=0;




    System.out.println("        INVENTORY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM");
    System.out.println("===============================================");
    System.out.println("1. ADD PRODUCT DATA");
    System.out.println("2. VIEW PRODUCT DATA");
    System.out.println("3. VIEW REPRLENISHMENT STRATEGY");
    System.out.println("===============================================");
    System.out.println("4. EXIT PROGRAM");

    while(n!=4)// Exits the program when 4 is pressed
    {
        System.out.print("\n Please enter option 1-4 to continue...: ");
        n = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
        // Reads user input and takes them to selected code.
        if (n>4||n<1)
        {
            System.out.print("Invalid input, please try again...");
            continue;
        }
        if (n==1)// Takes to option 1 or addItem()
        {
            str="y";
            while(str.equals("y")||str.equals("Y"))
            {

                Inv.addItem();
                System.out.print("Would you like to enter another product ? (Y or N) : ");
                str = console.next();
            }   
            continue;
        }
        if (n==2)// Takes to option 2 or prodData
        {
            str="y";
            while(str.equals("y")||str.equals("Y"))
            {
                Inv.prodData();
                System.out.println("\n***************************************************\n");
                System.out.print("Stay viewing this page? (Y or N) ");
                str = console.next();

            }
            continue;
        }
        else

        if (n==3)// Takes to option 3 or replenStrat
        {
            System.out.print("View Replenishment Strategy.");
            continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\nThank you for using this inventory management software.\n");
    System.out.print("Developed by Xavier Edwards");
    System.out.println("\n***************************************************\n");

}
// Global variables so that any class can call it and use the information in it
public static Product product;
public static Store store;
// Where the user inputs the data for the item
public static void addItem ()
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    product = new Product();// initiates the product and store to being empty.
    store = new Store();

    String desc, id, str="";
    double price = 0, sUpPrice = 0, unitCost = 0, inventoryCost = 0;
    int stock = 0, demand = 0;


        System.out.print("Please enter product description between 3 to 10 characters...: ");
        desc = console.next();
        desc = desc.toLowerCase();
        product.setName(desc);

        if ((desc.length() < 3 || desc.length() > 10))
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make description between 3 to 10 characters.\n");
            System.out.println("Try again with different input. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            Inv.addItem();
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter price in $ : ");
        price = console.nextDouble();
        product.setPrice(price);

        if (price < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
            System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            Inv.addItem();
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter set up price. $ : ");
        sUpPrice = console.nextDouble();
        product.setsUpPrice(sUpPrice);

        if (sUpPrice < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
            System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            Inv.addItem();
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter unit- cost. $ : ");
        unitCost = console.nextDouble();
        product.setunitCost(unitCost);

        if (unitCost < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
            System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            Inv.addItem();
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter the inventory cost. $ : ");
        inventoryCost = console.nextDouble();
        product.setinvCost(inventoryCost);

        if (inventoryCost < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
            System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            Inv.addItem();
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter the amount in stock : ");
        stock = console.nextInt();
        product.setstock(stock);

        if (stock < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
            System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            Inv.addItem();
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter the demand of the product : ");
        demand = console.nextInt();
        product.setdRate(demand);

        if (demand < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
            System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            Inv.addItem();
        }

        System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
        System.out.print(desc +" Product was added successfully ");
        System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
        // stores the item in the array
        store.add(product);


}
// Where the product information is being returned to the user
public static void prodData()
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String pOption, str;

    System.out.print("\nEnter product description to view the data...\n");
    pOption = console.next();//

    product = store.getProduct(pOption); //Checks to see if the item is created
                                        // so that data can be displayed
    if (product != null){
        System.out.println("Product description : "+product.getName());
        System.out.println("Price : $ "+product.getPrice());
        System.out.println("Set-up Price : $ "+product.getsUpPrice());
        System.out.println("Unit Cost : $ "+product.getunitCost());
        System.out.println("Inventory Cost : $ "+product.getinvCost());
        System.out.println("Amount of Stock : "+product.getstock());
        System.out.println("Amount of Stock : "+product.getdRate());
    }else{
        System.out.println("\nThere is no information on this product.\n");
        System.out.println("\nWould you like to try again? (Y or N) \n");
        str = console.next();
        Inv.prodData();
    }
}

}
```

code for Product.java

```
public class Product
{
    public String name;
    public double price, sUpPrice, unitCost, invCost;
    public int stock, demand;


    public Product()
    {
        name = "";
        price = 0;
        sUpPrice = 0;
        unitCost = 0;
        invCost = 0;
        stock = 0;
        demand = 0;

    }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
        public double getPrice() {
            return this.price;
        }   
        public void setsUpPrice(double sUpPrice) {
            this.sUpPrice = sUpPrice;
        }
        public double getsUpPrice() {
            return this.sUpPrice;
        }   
        public void setunitCost(double unitCost) {
            this.unitCost = unitCost;
        }
        public double getunitCost() {
            return this.unitCost;
        }   
        public void setinvCost(double invCost) {
            this.invCost = invCost;
        }
        public double getinvCost() {
            return this.invCost;
        }
        public void setstock(int stock) {
            this.stock = stock;
        }
        public int getstock() {
            return this.stock;
        }
        public void setdRate(int demand) {
            this.demand = demand;
        }
        public int getdRate() {
            return this.demand;
        }

}
```

code for store.java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Store{
public ArrayList <Product> ProductList = new ArrayList<Product> ();

public Store()
{
    //ArrayList = "";
}

public void add(Product product)
{           
    ProductList.add(product);
}

public Product getProduct(String prodName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ProductList.size(); i++) {
        if (ProductList.get(i).getName().equals(prodName)) {
            return ProductList.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
 }

}
```

any help be with appreciated.

Comment: *"from store.java there is an array which holds the information but when 2 items are attempted to be put in, the second object writes over the first"* No! As I can see, you are using `ArrayList` and not array and this scenario will only happen when you are using `set()` instead of `add()`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please use the formatting options.

Comment: you are correct, my bad in saying array, it was meant to be arrayList, so with that clarified how can i fix my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in `Inv.addItem()` method where you are instantiating variable `store` every time you invoke it.

```
store = new Store();
```

Looking at your code, you should instantiate it in `Inv`:

```
public static Store store = new Store();
```

Comment: thankyou so if i move it up to the start of Inv that should fix it

Comment: I haven't looked at whole code but yes this should fix your problem 
*second object writes over the first*